# Shotwell Automatically Starting

Tags: startup, iphone, photo

How do I stop Shotwell from launching automatically when I charge my iPhone in my laptop?

The program doesn't work (it never detects photos), plus I can just transfer the photos from the iPhone file manually. So I don't need the program and it is really annoying that it starts up all the time. How to prevent that?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5):

Go to System Settings -> Details -> Removable Media

and disable there Shotwell as a media handler program.

You can disable starting programs in all cases like I did.

[image]

Comment: You beat me by .5 seconds :)

Comment: Fantastic! <3 <3

Comment: On 18.04 it's now Settings -> Devices -> Removable Media